# Can we change Knox topology setting from ambari UI?

Tags: hadoop, ambari, hdp, knox-gateway, apache-knox

It is possible to change default topology of knox ( **default.xml** ) from **ambari** UI?

If yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can by going to **Ambari > Knox > Config > Advanced topology** in Ambari UI.